# How to fetch a non-ascii url with urlopen?

Tags: python, unicode, urllib2, non-ascii-characters, urlopen

I need to fetch data from a URL with non-ascii characters but urllib2.urlopen refuses to open the resource and raises:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0131' in position 26: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I know the URL is not standards compliant but I have no chance to change it.

What is the way to access a resource pointed by a URL containing non-ascii characters using Python?

**edit:** In other words, can / how urlopen open a URL like:

```
http://example.org/Ñöñ-ÅŞÇİİ/
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Strictly speaking URIs can't contain non-ASCII characters; what you have there is an [IRI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_Resource_Identifier).

To convert an IRI to a plain ASCII URI:

- non-ASCII characters in the hostname part of the address have to be encoded using the [Punycode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode)-based IDNA algorithm;
- non-ASCII characters in the path, and most of the other parts of the address have to be encoded using UTF-8 and %-encoding, as per Ignacio's answer.

So:

```
import re, urlparse

def urlEncodeNonAscii(b):
    return re.sub('[\x80-\xFF]', lambda c: '%%%02x' % ord(c.group(0)), b)

def iriToUri(iri):
    parts= urlparse.urlparse(iri)
    return urlparse.urlunparse(
        part.encode('idna') if parti==1 else urlEncodeNonAscii(part.encode('utf-8'))
        for parti, part in enumerate(parts)
    )

>>> iriToUri(u'http://www.a\u0131b.com/a\u0131b')
'http://www.xn--ab-hpa.com/a%c4%b1b'
```

(Technically this still isn't quite good enough in the general case because `urlparse` doesn't split away any `user:pass@` prefix or `:port` suffix on the hostname. Only the hostname part should be IDNA encoded. It's easier to encode using normal `urllib.quote` and `.encode('idna')` at the time you're constructing a URL than to have to pull an IRI apart.)

Comment: Although this seems to be a very niche problem, it's sure resolved a very specific issue of my own. Great answer.

Comment: How to handle this elegantly in Python 3? Any suggestions?

Comment: This actually works great for serving files where the name may contain non-american characters such as kanji symbols!

Comment: in python 3 you `import urllib.parse` instead of `urlparse`, decode b in urlEncodeNonAscii: `b.decode('utf-8')` and leave the idna part out of the iriToUri:  `return urllib.parse.urlunparse([url_encode_non_ascii(part.encode('utf-8')) for  part in parts])`

Comment: Using UTF-8 for query is not always correct; details are in my answer. Web is a weird place.

Comment: AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'unparse'

Comment: This doesn't encode spaces.  To add that, include something like `re.sub(r'\s', '+', str)`

Answer (score 50):

In python3, use the `urllib.parse.quote` function on the non-ascii string:

```
>>> from urllib.request import urlopen                                                                                                                                                            
>>> from urllib.parse import quote                                                                                                                                                                
>>> chinese_wikipedia = 'http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:' + quote('首页')
>>> urlopen(chinese_wikipedia)
```

Comment: Simple and effective! :D

Comment: Much better than the other answers.

Comment: This is a wonderful solution.  Solved my issue when using Kanji with urls, works with Japanese character sets.

Comment: WOW This is underrated

Comment: Note this doesn't handle the hostname (IDNA) correctly.

Comment: Worked for me for greek and strange chars like o with umlaut (German)

Answer (score 27):

Python 3 has libraries to handle this situation.  Use
`urllib.parse.urlsplit` to split the URL into its components, and
`urllib.parse.quote` to properly quote/escape the unicode characters
and `urllib.parse.urlunsplit` to join it back together.

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> url = 'http://example.com/unicodè'
>>> url = urllib.parse.urlsplit(url)
>>> url = list(url)
>>> url[2] = urllib.parse.quote(url[2])
>>> url = urllib.parse.urlunsplit(url)
>>> print(url)
http://example.com/unicod%C3%A8
```

Comment: @user230137 What do you mean it doesn't work?  Works perfectly for me.

Comment: Note this doesn't handle the hostname (IDNA) correctly.

Comment: urllib.parse.quote(url, safe=':/')

Answer (score 7):

It is more complex than the accepted @bobince's answer suggests:

- netloc should be encoded using IDNA;
- non-ascii URL path should be encoded to UTF-8 and then percent-escaped;
- non-ascii query parameters should be encoded to the encoding of a page URL was extracted from (or to the encoding server uses), then percent-escaped.

This is how all browsers work; it is specified in https://url.spec.whatwg.org/ - see this [example](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#query-encoding-example). A Python implementation can be found in w3lib (this is the library Scrapy is using); see [w3lib.url.safe_url_string](https://github.com/scrapy/w3lib/blob/5918d0e467279195ca41257ad0ba4037c98a34e2/w3lib/url.py#L71):

```
from w3lib.url import safe_url_string
url = safe_url_string(u'http://example.org/Ñöñ-ÅŞÇİİ/', encoding="<page encoding>")
```

An easy way to check if a URL escaping implementation is incorrect/incomplete is to check if it provides 'page encoding' argument or not.

Answer (score 7):

Based on @darkfeline answer:

```
from urllib.parse import urlsplit, urlunsplit, quote

def iri2uri(iri):
    """
    Convert an IRI to a URI (Python 3).
    """
    uri = ''
    if isinstance(iri, str):
        (scheme, netloc, path, query, fragment) = urlsplit(iri)
        scheme = quote(scheme)
        netloc = netloc.encode('idna').decode('utf-8')
        path = quote(path)
        query = quote(query)
        fragment = quote(fragment)
        uri = urlunsplit((scheme, netloc, path, query, fragment))

    return uri
```

Comment: This has some issues 1) scheme does not support percentage encoded chars, 2) path and query have different chars that are safe than path and those should not be percent-encoded, the default safe chars for quote is for the path component - werkzeug has a better iri2uri implementation [[ref](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/92c6380248c7272ee668e1f8bbd80447027ccce2/src/werkzeug/urls.py#L926-L931)].

Answer (score 5):

For those not depending strictly on urllib, one practical alternative is [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), which handles IRIs "out of the box".

For example, with `http://bücher.ch`:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get(u'http://b\u00DCcher.ch')
>>> r.status_code
200
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks! In my case I was trying to download a file (.png) in bytes format.
My original code:
`urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()`



The code after the change to requests:
`requests.get(url).content`

Answer (score 4):

Encode the `unicode` to UTF-8, then URL-encode.

Comment: thanks for the response. can you be more specific please? `unicode(url, 'utf-8')` raises `TypeError: decoding Unicode is not supported`. also which function do you suggest for encoding url? urlencode for example is for building query string. but mine is only a path on the server.

Comment: http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/ http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote

Comment: For the first part, you want `url.encode('utf-8')` (assuming `url` is a `unicode` object).

Comment: @ignacio: thanks. i still think the problem is with the urlopen not accepting non-ascii characters as a URL (which it is right in a way, as they are not standard). please see my update in question.

Answer (score 4):

Use `iri2uri` method of `httplib2`. It makes the same thing as by bobin (is he/she the author of that?)

Comment: The proposed solution doesn't work for non-ASCII domain names (IRI). `urllib2.urlopen(httplib2.iri2uri("http://домены.рф"), timeout=15)` returns **urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known**

Answer (score 1):

Another option to convert an IRI to an ASCII URI is to use `furl` package:

gruns/furl:  URL parsing and manipulation made easy. - https://github.com/gruns/furl

> Python's standard urllib and urlparse modules provide a number of URL
> related functions, but using these functions to perform common URL
> operations proves tedious. Furl makes parsing and manipulating URLs
> easy.

### Examples

#### Non-ASCII domain

[http://国立極地研究所.jp/english/](http://xn--vcsoey76a2hh0vtuid5qa.jp/english/) (Japanese National Institute of Polar Research website)

```py
import furl

url = 'http://国立極地研究所.jp/english/'
furl.furl(url).tostr()
```

```
'http://xn--vcsoey76a2hh0vtuid5qa.jp/english/'
```

#### Non-ASCII path

[https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/日本語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E) ("Japanese" article in Wikipedia)

```py
import furl

url = 'https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/日本語'
furl.furl(url).tostr()
```

```
'https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E'
```

Answer (score 0):

### works! finally

I could not avoid from this strange characters, but at the end I come through it.

```
import urllib.request
import os


url = "http://www.fourtourismblog.it/le-nuove-tendenze-del-marketing-tenere-docchio/"
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as file:
    html = file.read()
with open("marketingturismo.html", "w", encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write(str(html.decode('utf-8')))
os.system("marketingturismo.html")
```