# Opening page using urllib2 - diacritics

Tags: python, html, urllib2

I'm trying to open multiple pages using urllib2. The problem is that some pages can't be opened. It returns `urllib2.HTTPerror: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request`

I'm getting hrefs of this pages from another web page (in the head of the page is charset = "utf-8").
The error is returned only then, when I'm trying to open a page containing 'č','ž' or 'ř' in url.

Here is the code:

```
def getSoup(url):
    req = urllib2.Request(url)

    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    page = response.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    return soup




hovienko = getSoup("http://www.hovno.cz/hovna-az/a/1/")
lis = hovienko.find("div", class_="span12").find('ul').findAll('li')

for liTag in lis:

    aTag = liTag.find('a')['href']
    href = "http://www.hovno.cz"+aTag  """ hrefs, I'm trying to open using urllib2 """
    soup = getSoup(href.encode("iso-8859-2")) """ here occures errors when 'č','ž' or 'ř' in url """
```

Do anybody knows, what I have to do to avoid errors?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was very simple. I should used urllib2.quote().

EDITED CODE:

```
for liTag in lis:

    aTag = liTag.find('a')['href']
    href = "http://www.hovno.cz"+urllib2.quote(aTag.encode("utf-8"))
    soup = getSoup(href)
```

Answer (score 1):

This site is UTF-8. Why you need href.encode("iso-8859-2") ? I have taken the next code from http://programming-review.com/beautifulsoasome-interesting-python-functions/

```
    import urllib2
    import cgitb
    cgitb.enable()
    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
    from urlparse import urlparse

# print all links
def PrintLinks(localurl):
    data = urllib2.urlopen(localurl).read()
    print 'Encoding of fetched HTML : %s', type(data)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
    parse = urlparse(localurl)
    localurl = parse[0] + "://" + parse[1]
    print "<h3>Page links statistics</h3>"
    l = soup.findAll("a", attrs={"href":True})
    print "<h4>Total links count = " + str(len(l)) + '</h4>'
    externallinks = [] # external links list
    for link in l:
    # if it's external link
        if link['href'].find("http://") == 0 and link['href'].find(localurl) == -1:
            externallinks = externallinks + [link]
    print "<h4>External links count = " + str(len(externallinks)) + '</h4>'


    if len(externallinks) > 0:
        print "<h3>External links list:</h3>"
        for link in externallinks:
          if link.text != '':
            print '<h5>' + link.text.encode('utf-8')
            print ' => [' + '<a href="' + link['href'] + '" >' + link['href'] + '</a>' +  ']' + '</h5>'
          else:
            print '<h5>' + '[image]',
            print ' => [' + '<a href="' + link['href'] + '" >' + link['href'] + '</a>' +  ']' + '</h5>'


PrintLinks( "http://www.zlatestranky.cz/pro-mobily/")
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things here.

First, you URIs can't contain non-ASCII. You have to replace them. See this:
[How to fetch a non-ascii url with Python urlopen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389572/how-to-fetch-a-non-ascii-url-with-python-urlopen)

Secondly, save yourself a world of pain and use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) for HTTP stuff.

Comment: Thank you Bobby, I've already solved it using urllib2.quote(). Could you tell me how using requests could help me with my code? For example on this code below. Thank you

Comment: The requests library has a much better API. See [this example](https://gist.github.com/kennethreitz/973705) for a hint at what I'm talking about.