# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python

I have a Python script which uses tinypng api to convert images recursively and for some reason it does not work and I get:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal
>   not in range(128)

What am I doing wrong?

```
import os
import base64
from os.path import dirname
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen
from base64 import b64encode

compress_png = True 
compress_jpg = True
import_dir = '666\product'
output_dir = '666\product'
tiny_png_key = 'xxxxxx'
tiny_png_url = 'https://api.tinypng.com/shrink'

img_count = 0
file_count = 0
compress_count = 0
existing_count = 0


def compressImage(filepath, filedest, overwrite = True):
    global compress_count
    global existing_count
    if not os.path.isfile(filedest) or overwrite: 
        status = ''
        request = Request(tiny_png_url, open(filepath, "rb").read())
        auth = b64encode(bytes("api:" + tiny_png_key)).decode("ascii")
        request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % auth)
        response = urlopen(request)

        if response.getcode() == 201:
            status = "success";
            headers = response.info()
            result = urlopen(headers["Location"]).read()

            if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(filedest)):
                os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filedest))
            open(filedest, "wb").write(result)
            compress_count += 1
        else:
            status = "failed"
        print 'Compressing: %s\nFile: %s\nStatus: %s\n'%(filepath, img_count, status)
    else:
        existing_count += 1


# loop througs files in import_dir recursively 
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(import_dir):
    for file in files:
        filepath = os.path.join(subdir, file)
        fileName, fileExtension = os.path.splitext(file)
        file_count += 1
        if(fileExtension == '.png' and compress_png) or (fileExtension == '.jpg' and compress_jpg):
            img_count += 1
            filedest = filepath.replace(import_dir, output_dir)
            compressImage(filepath, filedest)


print '================'
print 'Total Files: %s'%(file_count)
print 'Total Images: %s'%(img_count)
print 'Images Compressed: %s'%(compress_count)
print 'Images Previously Compressed (Exist in output directory): %s'%(existing_count)
```

Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Vygantas\Desktop\test.py", line 55, in <module> compressImage(filepath, filedest)
    File "C:\Users\Vygantas\Desktop\test.py", line 28, in compressImage response = urlopen(request)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 391, in open response = self._open(req, data)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 409, in _open '_open', req)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain result = func(*args)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1181, in https_open return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1142, in do_open h.request(req.get_method(), req.get_selector(), req.data, headers)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 946, in request self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 987, in _send_request self.endheaders(body)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 940, in endheaders self._send_output(message_body)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 801, in _send_output msg += message_body UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: General advice. Strip the code down to a bare minimum and then learn some debugging techniques. Often just staring at the code is not enough.

Comment: what the purpose of 
"auth = b64encode(bytes("api:" + tiny_png_key)).decode("ascii")"

Comment: Without I get

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 55, in <module>
    compressImage(filepath, filedest)
  File "", line 28, in compressImage
    response = urlopen(request)
  File "urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "urllib2.py", line 397, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "urllib2.py", line 510, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "urllib2.py", line 435, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)

Comment: File "urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "urllib2.py", line 518, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fetch a non-ascii url with Python urlopen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389572/how-to-fetch-a-non-ascii-url-with-python-urlopen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the example on the website and adapting it to Python 2 the same way you did seems to work for me:

```
from os.path import dirname
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen
from base64 import b64encode

key = "xxxx_xxxx"
input = "NLMK.png"
output = "tiny-output.png"

request = Request("https://api.tinypng.com/shrink", open(input, "rb").read())

auth = b64encode("api:" + key).decode("ascii")
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % auth)

response = urlopen(request)
if response.getcode() == 201:
    # Compression was successful, retrieve output from Location header.
    headers = response.info()
    result = urlopen(headers["Location"]).read()
    open(output, "wb").write(result)
else:
    # Something went wrong! You can parse the JSON body for details.
    print("Compression failed")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to encode the data but not the user name
I would try something like:

```
def compressImage(filepath, filedest, overwrite = True):
    global compress_count
    global existing_count
    if not os.path.isfile(filedest) or overwrite: 
        status = ''
        data = open(filepath, "rb").read()
        data = base64.b64encode(data)
        request = Request(tiny_png_url, data)
        request.add_header("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8")
        auth = "api:" + tiny_png_key
        request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % auth)
        response = urlopen(request)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, but got error on this line:

   request = Request(tiny_png_url, data))

   request = Request(tiny_png_url, data))
                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Changed to

   request = Request(tiny_png_url, data)

Still errro

  File "test.py", line 33
    if response.getcode() == 201:
                                ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Comment: But I'm not sure my answer is good. I have made some test with a code that looks more your original one and it works fine for me. I doubts now that this answer is relevant. I'm thinking about deleting it.