# Unable to parse Non ASCII URL on Python?

Tags: python-2.7, urllib

I wanted to query Freebase API to get the list of teams José Mourinho has played for.

So, the URL i used on my browser is

```
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?query=[{"name": "José Mourinho","/sports/pro_athlete/teams": [{"mid": null,"team": null,"to": null,"optional": true}]}]
```

However,

```
import json
import urllib

service_url="https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread"
query = '[{"name": "' + "José Mourinho" + '","/sports/pro_athlete/teams": [{"mid": null,"team": null,"to": null,"optional": true}]}]'
url = service_url + '?' + 'query='+query
response = json.loads(urllib.urlopen(url).read())
```

Gives me an error saying,

```
UnicodeError: URL u'https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?query=[{"name": "Jos\xe9 Mourinho","/sports/pro_athlete/teams": [{"mid": null,"team": null,"to": null,"optional": true}]}]' contains non-ASCII characters
```

What is the solution to this?

Comment: [strictly speaking, urls cannot have non-ascii characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389572/how-to-fetch-a-non-ascii-url-with-python-urlopen)

Comment: I know that actually. But is there any hack/bypass for this in Python?

Comment: @RNar I saw that before posting it. The solution gives me the error where I decode it twice.

Comment: did you try using [urllib.parse.quote](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18269491/5323213)?

Comment: I'm using python 2.7. It works only in 3

Comment: then use [`urllib.quote`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote)

Comment: Out of curiosity (and love of the library), what happens if you use [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you skipped over a little bit of [the docs](https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/mql-overview?hl=en). Try this instead:

```
# coding=UTF-8

import json
import urllib

service_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread"
query = [{
    '/sports/pro_athlete/teams': [
        {
            'to': None,
            'optional': True,
            'mid': None,
            'team': None
        }
    ],
    'name': 'José Mourinho'
}]

url = service_url + '?' + urllib.urlencode({'query': json.dumps(query)})
response = json.loads(urllib.urlopen(url).read())

print response
```

Rather than building the query string yourself, use `json.dumps` and `urllib.urlencode` to create it for you. They're good at this.

Note: if you can use the `requests` package, that last bit could be:

```
import requests
response = requests.get(service_url, params={'query': json.dumps(query)})
```

Then you get to skip the URL construction and escaping altogether!

Comment: Fantastic Solution. Bravo