# problem of urlretrieve cannot get image from url contains unicode string

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, python-unicode

I write a python script to retrieve the image from url:

```
url = `https://uploads0.wikiart.org/images/albrecht-durer/watermill-at-the-montaсa.jpg`
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, STYLE_IMAGE_UPLOAD + "wikiart" + "/" + url)
```

When I run I got the message

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u0441' in position 49: ordinal not in range(128)`

I think the problem from the image url

`'https://uploads0.wikiart.org/images/albrecht-durer/watermill-at-the-monta\u0441a.jpg',`

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace? Also, your code snippet isn't reproducible, as we don't know what `STYLE_IMAGE_UPLOAD` is.

Comment: Oh I see, the "c" in "Montaca" is a Cyrillic letter. Have you tried url-encoding the address?

Comment: Btw, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4389572)'s a collection of more general approaches and alternative solutions. For example, I learned that the `requests` library handles addresses like that out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL contains a non-ASCII character (a Cyrillic letter that looks like a Latin "c").

Escape this character using the `urllib.parse.quote` function:

```
url = 'https://uploads0.wikiart.org' + urllib.parse.quote('/images/albrecht-durer/watermill-at-the-montaсa.jpg')
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, '/tmp/watermill.jpg')
```

Don't put the entire URL in the `quote` function, otherwise it would escape the colon (":") in "https://".