# How to deal with the 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe9' error?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to download Excel files from the website.  My code below:

```
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# Python 3.x
from urllib.request import urlopen, urlretrieve, quote
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import urllib

headers={"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36"}
resp = requests.get("https://www.elections.on.ca/en/resource-centre/elections-results.html#accordion2022ge")
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text,"html.parser")

for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
#    print(link)
    if 'xlsx' in link['href']:
        print(link['href'])
        url="https://www.elections.on.ca/"+link['href']
#        print(url)
        file= url.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]+".xlsx"
#        print(file)
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, file)
```

However, I get the following error when [https://www.elections.on.ca//content/dam/NGW/sitecontent/2022/results/Vote%20Totals%20From%20Official%20Tabulation%20-%20OrlÃ©ans%20076.xlsx](https://www.elections.on.ca//content/dam/NGW/sitecontent/2022/results/Vote%20Totals%20From%20Official%20Tabulation%20-%20Orl%C3%83%C2%A9ans%20076.xlsx) is trying to be opened

```
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-e1694f5ee458> in <module>
      8         file= url.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]+".xlsx"
      9 #        print(file)
---> 10         urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, file)
...

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 101-102: ordinal not in range(128).
```

EDIT: I tried the `safeStr` solution form [UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20), but it does not work. Please see below:

```
def safeStr(obj):
    try: return str(obj).encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
    except: return ""

url="https://www.elections.on.ca/"+'/content/dam/NGW/sitecontent/2022/results/Vote%20Totals%20From%20Official%20Tabulation%20-%20Orléans%20076.xlsx'
#        print(url)
print(url)
file= url.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]+".xlsx"
url = safeStr(url)
print(url)
#        print(file)
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, file)
```

The error I get is:

```
https://www.elections.on.ca//content/dam/NGW/sitecontent/2022/results/Vote%20Totals%20From%20Official%20Tabulation%20-%20Orléans%20076.xlsx
https://www.elections.on.ca//content/dam/NGW/sitecontent/2022/results/Vote%20Totals%20From%20Official%20Tabulation%20-%20Orlans%20076.xlsx

HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-01070419a054> in <module>
      6 print(url)
      7 #        print(file)
----> 8 urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, file)

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in urlretrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
    245     url_type, path = _splittype(url)
    246 
--> 247     with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
    248         headers = fp.info()
    249 

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    220     else:
    221         opener = _opener
--> 222     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    223 
    224 def install_opener(opener):

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    529         for processor in self.process_response.get(protocol, []):
    530             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
--> 531             response = meth(req, response)
    532 
    533         return response

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in http_response(self, request, response)
    638         # request was successfully received, understood, and accepted.
    639         if not (200 <= code < 300):
--> 640             response = self.parent.error(
    641                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    642 

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in error(self, proto, *args)
    567         if http_err:
    568             args = (dict, 'default', 'http_error_default') + orig_args
--> 569             return self._call_chain(*args)
    570 
    571 # XXX probably also want an abstract factory that knows when it makes

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    500         for handler in handlers:
    501             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 502             result = func(*args)
    503             if result is not None:
    504                 return result

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    647 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    648     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 649         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    650 
    651 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

I tried another solution from [problem of urlretrieve cannot get image from url contains unicode string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59227588/problem-of-urlretrieve-cannot-get-image-from-url-contains-unicode-string/59228276#59228276), but it also does not work:

```
url = "https://www.elections.on.ca/"+urllib.parse.quote('/content/dam/NGW/sitecontent/2022/results/Vote%20Totals%20From%20Official%20Tabulation%20-%20Orléans%20076.xlsx')
#url = safeStr(url)
print(url)
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, file)
```

The error I get is:

```
https://www.elections.on.ca//content/dam/NGW/sitecontent/2022/results/Vote%2520Totals%2520From%2520Official%2520Tabulation%2520-%2520Orl%C3%A9ans%2520076.xlsx

HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-cfce9d1344d0> in <module>
      2 #url = safeStr(url)
      3 print(url)
----> 4 urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, file)

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in urlretrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
    245     url_type, path = _splittype(url)
    246 
--> 247     with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
    248         headers = fp.info()
    249 

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    220     else:
    221         opener = _opener
--> 222     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    223 
    224 def install_opener(opener):

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    529         for processor in self.process_response.get(protocol, []):
    530             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
--> 531             response = meth(req, response)
    532 
    533         return response

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in http_response(self, request, response)
    638         # request was successfully received, understood, and accepted.
    639         if not (200 <= code < 300):
--> 640             response = self.parent.error(
    641                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    642 

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in error(self, proto, *args)
    567         if http_err:
    568             args = (dict, 'default', 'http_error_default') + orig_args
--> 569             return self._call_chain(*args)
    570 
    571 # XXX probably also want an abstract factory that knows when it makes

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    500         for handler in handlers:
    501             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 502             result = func(*args)
    503             if result is not None:
    504                 return result

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    647 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    648     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 649         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    650 
    651 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Comment: show more of the traceback - which line of the code you posted does the error come from?

Comment: Hello, I have added some more info about the error. I can't post the complete error as the stackoverflow complains that it is too much code.

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59228276/202168

Comment: Please see the post edit.

Comment: @IsaacA Try using Unicode. `'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe9' ` means the character you are trying to encode is not an ASCII character.

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake in edit. Corrected it now. Will reply with an update regarding using the Unicode.

Comment: @IsaacA See [urllib.parse.urlencode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode).  Also refer to https://stackoverflow.com/q/6480723/8659747

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a solution...

The problem is that the url you start with:

```py
"https://www.elections.on.ca/content/dam/NGW/sitecontent/2022/results/Vote%20Totals%20From%20Official%20Tabulation%20-%20Orléans%20076.xlsx'
```

is already url-quoted (e.g. spaces replaced by `%20`), but still contains non-ascii chars here `Orléans`

So the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59228276/202168) will help us, but just applying `urllib.parse.quote(...)` results in twice-encoded spaces as `%2520`. That is why you get a 404 when requesting the processed url.

So first we need to unquote the url (i.e. `%20 ->> " "`), then quote it again - this time the accented char will be quoted too and it should work.

Try this:

```py
path = urllib.parse.quote(urllib.parse.unquote(link['href']))
url = "https://www.elections.on.ca" + path
```

The result we get is:

```
https://www.elections.on.ca/content/dam/NGW/sitecontent/2022/results/Vote%20Totals%20From%20Official%20Tabulation%20-%20Orl%C3%A9ans%20076.xlsx
```

...should work now!