# Passing a non ascii character in steam url

Tags: python, url, encoding, urllib

I'm trying to fetch the price of an item `StatTrak™ Dual Berettas | Panther (Factory New)`. however the TM is causing issue as urllib treats it as a non-ascii character. I've found this [How to fetch a non-ascii url with urlopen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389572/how-to-fetch-a-non-ascii-url-with-urlopen) but for whatever reason steam is passing a 500 error

```
from urllib.parse import quote 

def get_price(item_name):
    base_url = 'http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=730&currency=1&market_hash_name={}'
    print(base_url.format(quote(item_name)))
    request = urllib.request.urlopen(base_url.format(quote(item_name)))
```

Output URL (after parse): http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=730&currency=1&market_hash_name=StatTrak%E2%84%A2%2520Dual%2520Berettas%2520%7C%2520Panther%2520%28Factory%2520New%29

Working url (done in browser): [https://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=730&currency=1&market_hash_name=StatTrak%E2%84%A2%20Dual%20Berettas%20|%20Panther%20(Factory%20New)](https://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=730&currency=1&market_hash_name=StatTrak%E2%84%A2%20Dual%20Berettas%20%7C%20Panther%20(Factory%20New))

I seem to need to pass this, but urllib won't allow me to. What could I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code seems to work fine:

```
>>> base_url = 'http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=730&currency=1&market_hash_name={}'
>>> urllib.request.urlopen(base_url.format(quote("StatTrak™ Dual Berettas | Panther (Factory New)"))).read()
b'{"success":true,"lowest_price":"$5.80","volume":"3","median_price":"$4.53"}'
```

I believe your issue arises because of double quoting. The `%2520` in your "Output URL" means you quoted a single space (`%20`) twice (`' ' -> %20 -> %2520`).

Your code however seems to quote only once, which is good. You must have passed the item already quoted to the function.